# How to create a bar chart based on the presented data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bar-chart

[image: Data Frame]

I am trying to produce a bar chart for the data frame above and I am having issues doing so.  My code for this data frame is:

```
high_pay[['Sport', 'Name', 'Year', 'earnings ($ million)']] \
    .sort_values('earnings ($ million)', ascending=False) \
    .drop_duplicates('Sport', keep='first')
```

What would be the appropriate way to put this information in a bar chart where `Sport` is on the x axis and `earnings ($ million)` is on the y axis?

Comment: Groupby sport, sum the earnings?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you can do that with something like the following.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

high_pay = pd.DataFrame({'Sport': ['Boxing','Soccer','Golf','Tennis','MMA','NFL','NBA','Auto Racing','Baseball','Hockey','Cycling','American Football / Baseball'],
                   'Earnings ($ million)': [300,127,115,106.3,99,89.5,89,80,35,29.8,28,22.5]
                   })


plt.bar(high_pay["Sport"].values, high_pay['Earnings ($ million)'].values)
#format labels on x-axis
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Brendan, thank you so much!